# Test if function is called after script load

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a single javascript file to test, and it ends with line:

```
window.vioInit && setTimeout(window.vioInit, 0);
```

So right after script is loaded, it calls function `vioInit` if it exists. I want to cover this case with test. I use [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/index.html) and [jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html). For now I have next spec:

```
describe("VIO initialization. ", function() {
    window.vioInit = new Function();

    beforeEach(function() {
        window.vioInit = new Function();
        spyOn(window, 'vioInit');
    });

    it("window.vioInit() should be called on script load", function() {
        expect(window.vioInit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

But it fails with output:

```
E:\webdev\hapi>karma start karma.conf.js
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.23 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket ttEs4AgYPQxCUB_-XG43 with id 8200833

PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) VIO initialization.  window.vioInit() should be called on script load FAILED
        Expected spy vioInit to have been called.
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.013 secs / 0.003 secs)
```

So how do I set a spy on `window.vioInit` before script is loaded and check if it was called after script was loaded?

Comment: The test is failing because the call is made asynchronously - the method call doesn't happen until after the test has finished running. If you remove the `setTimeout` wrapper, I'd expect it to work. You need to find out how to verify async method calls in Jasmine.

Comment: I changed last line to ``window.vioInit();`` and got ``TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window.vioInit()')
at E:/webdev/hapi/hapi/public/static/partner/vio-api.js:9``. But thanks for pointing me to async methods in Jasmine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of debugging I came to the next solution:

```
describe("VIO initialization. ", function () {
    window.vioInit = jasmine.createSpy("vioInit spy");

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            // waiting for vioInit to be called
            done();
        }, 10)
    });

    it("window.vioInit() should be called on script load", function (done) {
        expect(window.vioInit).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    });
});
```

Also note, that in karma configuration your test specs must be included before your source code:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        // ...
        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'hapi/public/partner_fe/tests/**/*.js',
            'hapi/public/static/partner/vio-api.js'
        ],
        // ...
    });
};
```

Docs: [Jasmine Asynchronous Support](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support), [Jasmine Spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies), [Karma Configuration File](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html)